# Spring deserialize JSON to Java class

Tags: java, json, spring

Нужно срочно поднять сервис, а он валится от того, что ему приходит не такой `response` как он ожидает для того, что спарсить `json` в класс. 
Моделька имеет вид:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="DeliveryOrder")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DeliveryOrder {

@XmlElement(name="Company")
private String company;

@XmlElement(name="Number")
private String number;

@XmlElement(name="Address")
private String address; 

//getters setters
}
```

Отправляю `json`:

```
{ 
  "Company" : "test",
  "Number" : "test",
  "Address" : "test"
}
```

И спринг его не парсит. 
Никогда раньше не работал с этими аннотациями `Xml`, а только с `Jackson Mapper` и насколько помню, нужно же чтобы имя поля было как указано в `name`, чтобы можно было его спарсить с `response body` в класс. 
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ она там есть, просто в примере не указал

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а, исправил. спасибо

Comment: что то я не пойму почему на входе json а ждете вы xml

Comment: @StrangerintheQ жду так же json. Как сейчас оказалось, оно не делает анмаршал потому, что спринаговый метод support(DeliverOrder.class) возвращает false

Comment: зачем тогда аннотации @Xml... ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я честно хз зачем, у меня локально даже сорсов нету, все что я могу делать это read-only по ssh и запускать томкат с варкой в которой стукаюсь уже через постман. Как мне сказали фикс должен быть в сервисе, который этот джейсон возвращает джаве. Вот и играюсь с этим  респонсом почти неделю

Comment: вот Вы написали про jackson, им бы и парсили

Comment: @StrangerintheQ была бы возможность вносить изменения в этот сервис, я бы постарался как-то переписать, но как уже указал выше, права только на read-only

Comment: ну он ждет на вход не Json а xml, насколько я понимаю происходящее

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96812/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-raviga).

Answer (score 0):

А попробуйте твкой формат запроса.

```
{
    "company":"test",
    "number":"test",
    "address":"test"
}
```

Comment: пробовал, не работает тоже. до сих пор проблема не решена еще

Comment: Обновил свой ответ, проверьте